# How to mint multiple NFT images?

Tags: solidity, nft

Lets say I want to mint 1000 NFT's same image but their name is numbered 1-1000. Is it better to set a max supply of 1000, or to run the mint function 1000 times?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Standard you are using.

With `ERC721` tokens a batch mint is not possible (so you would have to call the `mint(...)` function 1000 times), however if your contract uses the `ERC1155` standard, you can use the function `_mintBatch(address to, uint256[] ids, uint256[] amounts, bytes data)`. You can read more about the function [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc1155#ERC1155-_mintBatch-address-uint256---uint256---bytes-).

**Note** though that the function is an `internal` function, so you have to expose it by wrapping it in a custom function, and probably add some custom logic to when the caller is allowed to batch mint.

Also this answer assumes that you are using `@openzeppelin/contracts` for a safe implementation.